# How to Implement Message feature in website

Tags: mysql, sql, message

I have a table

```
____________________________________________________________
|                         Message                           |
|___________________________________________________________|
| Sender  |  Message    |    Receiver       |   message_id  |   
| John    | How Are You?|      Will         |       1       |
|_________|_____________|___________________|_______________|
```

In Will computer I am showing as follows

```
Message By:John
Message:How Are You?
```

Now Suppose John Deleted this message But i can't remove the record because Will has not yet deleted.Therefore I am running a update query

```
Update Message Set Sender='' where message_id=1;
```

But after doing that in will computer message changes as follows

```
 Message By:                    //Because i have changed sender to null
    Message:How Are You?
```

Now how can i overcome this error of not getting desired output

Comment: When John deleted his message why you wanted Will to go and delete?? When I send some message to Mr.X on skype and I delete that message then message from Mr.X window also get deleted.

Comment: I think he may be using "deleted" to mean "closed"

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble : In facebook, if Mr.X send message to Mr.Y, and delete it, it get deleted from both.

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble : let me test on facebook... You meant message.. right? not post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add seperate boolean ReadBySender and ReadByReciever columns and update those rather than the actual sender/reciever

Comment: iam currently doing the same so is here no way else than this?

Comment: What is the problem with this solution?

Comment: I don't want to attach two additional column to this table

Comment: You could keep the read reciepts in an entirely seperate table, but that is even more overhead than this solution. In general, you should not be trying to get more than one functionality out of a single column. It leads to bugs and difficult to understand code.

Comment: Of course, theer are other solutions that do not rely on databases at all for sending messages, but I assume that bridge has already been crossed

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the other answers (which both could definitely work) would be to have a separate "Inbox" table. Something that just linked up which messages were still in whose inbox, like:

```
__________________________
|        INBOX           |
|________________________|
| User    |  Message_id  |  
| John    |       1      | 
| Will    |       1      | 
|_________|______________|
```

Then when John deletes the message you delete that row from the inbox table:

```
__________________________
|        INBOX           |
|________________________|
| User    |  Message_id  |  
| Will    |      1       | 
|_________|______________|
```

This way is also nice because it separates the metadata that makes up a message from the info about where it is stored, what actions people have taken, etc.

Comment: Do you know that this is causing data redudancy

Comment: and how will i know who has sent and who has received

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble How does this introduce any redundancy? And you would know who sent and recieved from the message table in the OP's question.  I'll give you that you could make an argument for it being overkill in the simplest case, but it is also the cleanest/most normalized.

Comment: oh this message is id and i think that message column in your inbox table is message

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble Oh, yep, this is just the id. I will edit the answer to be clearer =)

Answer (score 1):

Just maintain two more column `boolean is_deleted(true/false) and deleted_by(S/R)` to maintain the message status deleted (*true or false*) and deleted_by (*Sender or Receiver*).

Answer (score 0):

Just include two more (enumeration) columns to indicate, who already deleted the message.

Then in order to show the message, make sure in your `WHERE` clause, that the respective value is not set already.

In any case retain the `Sender` and `Receiver` columns, so that you can output all message information and attach the message to the correct users.

Comment: iam currently doing the same so is here no way else than this?

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble I don't see any other feasible way.